# How to drag selected OnItemLongClick from one ViewPager item to another

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So I have a FragmentPagerAdapter with a bar fragment (ListFragment)  and a team fragment (ListFragment). When an item is long-clicked I want to be able to drag it from the teams tab and drop it on the bars tab to make a relationship. This would theoretically work similar to the home screen, where if I get close to the edge with the item I can got to the next screen.

UPDATES:

I am using 3.0+ or compatibility library.

I am trying to drag onto ANOTHER TAB, not within the same tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the level you are targeting.  If your application is designed to run on Android 3.0 or later, you can target the built-in [Drag and Drop API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html).

If your application needs to target an earlier version, [this is a good open-source library](http://doffm.posterous.com/drag-and-drop-in-android-20) ([Github page](https://github.com/doffm/android-dragarea)) thatI I've used before and tries to mirror the functionality of the built-in API for apps targeting 2.0 or later.

In either case, you would start a drag operation with `startDrag()` from the `onItemLongClick()` callback.

**Edit: Sorry for the confusion**

You would have to programmatically do the "tab" changes in your `ViewPager` based on the `DragEvent` data:

1. Since `ViewPager` is only part of the support library (and was not backported), you will probably have to attach an `OnDragEventListener` to its parent ViewGroup.
2. You can monitor the drag location while the `ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION` events fire to the listener.  Define a reasonable threshold that the finger must reach within the edge of the listening View and, when it gets there, call `setCurrentItem()` on the `ViewPager` to switch.
3. As long as your new tab was instantiated in the view hierarchy when you started the drag (this is controlled by `setOffscreenPageLimit()` on `ViewPager`), the views on the new page should also be candidates for a drop target, so they should be able to listen for the `ACTION_DROP` event.

HTH

Comment: No this doesn't work across the view pager elements. I am using 3.0+ and the startDrag works but it doesn't go to the other item in the viewpager. I will try to add more detail.

Comment: Also should be FragmentPagerAdapter not ViewPage my bad

Comment: @Jackie Updated with some more thoughts.