# android drag and drop to another page in viewpager

Tags: android

I have a viewpager with 4 fragment, each fragment is a gridview, when i dragging item (to swap their position) in gridview it's ok but i want to **drag item from a fragment to another fragment**, **like drag icon app in home screen from a screen to another screen**

My gridview has padding left, right, left, horizontal, vertical spacing (all of this are undropzone), so when i'm dragging item to the left(right) screen i cannot get X position to set currentPage because my item not in dropzone(ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION) now

please guide me
sorry my bad english

Comment: refer this link may be it could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489366/how-to-drag-selected-onitemlongclick-from-one-viewpager-item-to-another